# Azure Data Factory giving denied access error on SFTP while I have rights

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using a *Copy Data* activity to download a file from a SFTP server to ADLS and then delete it (*Deletes files after completion*, on the Source tab). I have read and write rights on the SFTP server.

The activity complete successfully when I turn off the *delete after completion* feature, but when I turn it on, I get the following error message and my pipeline fail:

> ```
> Failure happened on 'Sink' side.
> ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission
> denied to access
> '/out/myfile.csv.gz'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException,Message=Permission
> denied,Source=Renci.SshNet,'
> ```

I do not understand this permission denied access error message, as **I'm able to delete files from the SFTP server when I use Filezilla** or other tool, **using the same account**.

I'm also recently getting this same error message on another SFTP server which was working fine for months, with the pipeline in production.

I tried to put max concurrent connections to 1, disable "recursivity", nothing fix it.

Comment: can you check the service connection whether this is configured correctly?

Comment: It is configured correctly as the download from the SFTP server to ADLS works, it's the delete part that gives me the error.

Comment: @Alssanro did you find a fix for this? I'm running into the same issue